# Parse.com - how to get most searched query?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I can't find a tool in Parse.com analytics that can show me most popular query.

I have added parse analytics to my Android app so I can see data for each search, but can't get the most popular one. I see that Parse Analytics/Explorer could hide something that I 'm looking for but can't find it.

Anyone knows how to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://parse.com/apps/**app-name**/slow_queries .. Check the slow queries part under analytics. Not sure if this is what you are looking for. but it shows all the queries and the number of times they were called.